# Walk-around to actionPerformed() returning void

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, listeners

I am trying to use the MVC design.

In the model I wanted a method like this

```
public boolean changeSomeData(...){
    boolean b;
    //create a dialog with an OK button
    return b;
}
```

I want the method to return TRUE if the changes were actually made. The changes are done inside the actionPerformed method of the OK button.

My problem is that I can't write b=true; inside the actionPerform of the OK button, because I have to declare b as final in order to use it in the actionPerformed().

What I did is creating a class

```
private class MyBoolean {
    boolean b;
}
```

and then

```
public boolean changeSomeData(...){
    MyBoolean myBoolean;
    //create a dialog with an OK button
    actionPerformed(){
        //make changes in the data
        myBoolean.b=true;
    }
    boolean b = myBoolean.b;
    return b;
}
```

But I don't feel good about this solution and I wanted to know if it is correct what I did and if there is a better solution.
Should I better throw an exception if the changes aren't made? (for example, if the user clicks "cancel" instead of "ok")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the model I wanted a method like this ... //create a dialog with an OK button

I'd say this is a flaw already, since the model should not do anything with views directly.

A better approach would be to open the dialog (using the controller), register the controller for the ActionEvent of "OK" (and thus `actionPerformed`) and then do whatever changes should be done in that method.

Edit:

You might want to consider the following rough approach:

The views register themselves or associated classes to the model as listeners. Whenever the model is changed it fires events to notify the views of the change.

The controller registers itself on the views and is notified when the views change. If a user changes data, the controller then might open the dialog and only commit the changes of the user signals "OK". Thus the model has never to check itself if data needs to be changed. That is actually the controller's task and if the controller passes changes to the model, it should apply them.

Comment: Yes, I suspected that writing the dialog in the model was a flaw. My motivation to do it that way was that I wanted to improve the encapsulation of the data class:
(1)the controller says to the data class "the user wants to change some of your data" (no need for the controller to get data)
(2)the data class takes control and asks the user which is the exact change he wants.

But now I see that this goes against the MVC design. Everything worked easily when I moved the dialog to the controller class.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve your task is to keep a variable on the dialog that indicates if a successful change was made.  Then have a method that your model class calls to retrieve the value and return it.

Something like:

```
public boolean changeSomeData(...){
    //create a dialog with an OK button
    return dialog.isSuccess();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could make this code a bit cleaner...

```
public boolean changeSomeData() {

   // note that this is not a class boolean, no need to do extra autoboxing.

   boolean dataChanged = false;

   // check the old value against the new value
   // for classes

   if (oldvalue.equals(newValue)) {
      oldValue = newValue;
      dataChanged = true;
   }

   // for pimitives (built-ins)

   if (oldvalue == newValue) {
      oldValue = newValue;
      dataChanged = true;
   }

   // odds are good that the above action performed was supposed to call this
   // changeSomeData() and not the other way around.

   // if you must fire actionPerformed() when data has changed, then do so
   // like this, otherwise if it was added as part of the "solution" you can
   // skip it.

   if (dataChanged) {
      actionPeformed();
   }

   return dataChanged;
}
```

Note that this code is `Controller` code, as it manipulates the model directly, and (possibly) updates views.